# axios get/post can't access Fast API

Tags: reactjs, authentication, ssl, axios, fastapi

I am working on an react application where I have to use a lot of GET and POST requests. the frontend is using axios as http client, while the APIs are built with FASTAPI. currently, I am only using basic authentication (which requires username & password). the API has a UI hosted i.e. https://81.000.000.11. The origin has also been allowed by the backend. i.e.

```
origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "https://headacheapp.testenv.com",
]
```

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    # allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

The problem I am facing is: The requests from the application only works when I LOGIN TO THE API UI. i.e. https://81.000.000.11/login (maybe it stores my username and password idk somewhere in my browser hidden storage, so when I clear the browsing history, the requests again doesn't work from the application.)
p.s. IT WORKS PERFECTLY FINE VIA POSTMAN BASIC AUTH.

**this is how my GET REQUEST look like**

```
    await axios({
      url: `${apiUrl}/transactions/users/${state.user_id}`,
      method: 'get',
      crossDomain: true,
      headers: { 
          "Authorization": "Basic averylongwierdencryptedtokensharedbybackendteam==",
          'accept' : 'application/json',
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
      auth: { username: credentials.username, password: credentials.password },
  
    }).then((response) => {
      setAllTransactions(response.data);
      walletBalance(response);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    });
  }
```

**this is how my POST REQUEST look like**

```
      await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${apiUrl}/transactions`,
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            "Basic averylongwierdencryptedtokensharedbybackendteam=",
            'accept' : 'application/json',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        auth: {
          username: credentials.username,
          password: credentials.password,
        },
        data: {
          user_id: state.user_id,
          transaction_id: "",
          buy_sell: "buy",
          batch_date: "",
          acknowledge_date: "",
          price: finalPrice.amount,
          status: "pending",
        },
      }).then(function (response) {
        
        alert(response.data.detail);
        setAlert(false);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
```

Summary: the requests will only work from the browsers where I am logged in to FASTAPI UI, it will show Errors something like.

[image: http error image,]

I have tried everything I could, but now I am here to get help from experts. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is from the browser, and it's telling you that you're presenting an untrusted certificate from the FastAPI server.

The problem is that you're using HTTPS, but the certificate you've configured FastAPI with isn't trusted by your browser. You'll need to one of:

1. Run in insecure mode when developing (HTTP instead of HTTPS).
2. Buy a certificate from a trusted CA for your production domain ("headacheapp.testenv.com"), and configure your development DNS to point this at to your localhost.
3. Add the CA you've signed your FastAPI certificate with to your browser's trust chain. **Don't do this unless you really know what you're doing**.